# Drawing a number using stars in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote a code, that prints a number - be it negative or positive - using stars. My program reverses the number from the user's input and then chopping it into digits prints them one by one, but not in the same row. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n, i = 0, reverse = 0, digit;

    cout << "Enter an integer:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;


    if(n < 0){
     cout << "--"<<endl;
     n = n - 2*n;
     }

    while(n > 0){

        reverse = reverse*10 + n%10;

        n = n / 10;

    }

   while(reverse > 0){
        digit = reverse % 10;
        reverse = reverse / 10;


    if(digit == 0){ 
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << "* *"<<endl; 
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }
    if(digit == 1){
        cout << " * "<<endl;
        cout << "** "<<endl;
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }
    if(digit == 2){
        cout << "** "<<endl;
        cout << " * "<<endl;
        cout << " **"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }
    if(digit == 3){ 
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << " **"<<endl;
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }
    if(digit == 4){
        cout << "* *"<<endl;
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << "  *"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }
    if(digit == 5){
        cout << " **"<<endl;
        cout << " * "<<endl;
        cout << "** "<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }
    if(digit == 6){
        cout << "*  "<<endl;
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }
    if(digit == 7){
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << "  *"<<endl;
        cout << "  *"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }
    if(digit == 8){
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }
    if(digit == 9){
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << "***"<<endl;
        cout << "  *"<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        }

    }   
}
```

I'm curious, if there is any possible way to print the numbers in the same row, or if not any number, is it possible for a fixed digit number, for ex: a 3-digit number or a 4-digit number?
p.s. If there is any simple way (using only loops and of course (if-else)) don't write the full code, only a hint.

Comment: Beware, Homework is coming. :P

Comment: Build into 3 `std::string`, and finally print them.

Comment: @Spartacus indeed :P, it is a homework but I'm not asking for solutions :D

Comment: Rotate the asterisk patterns of the digits 90 degrees clockwise. You will need to rotate the screen 90 degrees countercockwise (or break your neck bending it sideways). If you do it in the other direction, you can save you the digit reversal.

Comment: @n.m. Probably the best solution to any problem on SO I have seem today. +1

Comment: Tips for posting here: (1) when your problem is solved, please do not substantially modify your question, such as removing code; (2) do not modify the code in the question to a working version. These guidelines help maintain the Q&A format. Finally, (3) please click the tick icon adjacent to the answer below that most helped you. This marks the question as solved. (4) Optionally, you may upvote any answer, to thank helpful people for their effort.

Answer (score 1):

Variables you need: 
digCount: for how many digits you have,
digits[digCount]: int array of the size of your digit count.

Set the variables and:

Make a loop from 0 to digCount. In this loop first write the top side of all the numbers, then middle and finally bottom side. To show what I mean:

Think you have 879:

```
for(int i = 0; i < digCount; i++)
{
    cout<< topofDigit[i] << \t;
}

cout << "\n";

for(int i = 0; i < digCount; i++)
{
    cout<< middleofDigit[i] << \t;
}

cout << "\n";

for(int i = 0; i < digCount; i++)
{
    cout<< bottomofDigit[i] << \t;
}

cout << "\n";
```

I hope it gives you an opinion. To illustrate more, this program will firstly write:

```
    ***    ***    ***

Then:

    ***      *    ***

And finally:

    ***      *      *

Final output:

    ***    ***    ***
    ***      *    ***
    ***      *      *
```

Comment: Thanks, i shouldn't use arrays, but i will find a way without using them.

Comment: You can use 3 variables for each number as top middle and bottom instead of arrays.

Comment: cout << topof8 << "\t";
    cout << topof7 << "\t";
    cout << topof9 << "\t";
    cout << middleof8 << "\t";
    cout << middleof7 << "\t";
    cout << middleof9 << "\t";
    cout << bottomof8 << "\t";
    cout << bottomof7 << "\t";
    cout << bottomof9 << "\t";

Answer (score 0):

This is the hint, Instead of print the star directly, try to use `std::string` (or array of char)

for example, this is the way I will store the star:

```
s[0][0]="***";
s[0][1]="* *";
s[0][2]="***";
```

then using `for` to iterate the `s` so you can print the first line of all numbers, then the second line, then the third line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the three lines at once go line by line. For each digit print just the first row (with spaces in between). Then repeat the process for middle and last line. Print endl only after the line is over.

So we need to first specify what the arrays look like in an efficient way. We will create char arrays.

```
char top_line[10][4] =    {"***", "  *", "** ", "***", "* *", " **", "*  ", "***", "***", "***" };
char middle_line[10][4] = {"* *", "  *", " * ", " **", "***", " * ", "***", "  *", "***", "***" }; 
char bottom_line[10][4] = {"***", "  *", " **", "***", "  *", "** ", "***", "  *", "***", "  *" };   
cout <<"Enter a number:";
int n;
cin >> n;
int n_copy = n;
// We count the number of digits in n;
int digits = 1;
while(n) {
    n/=10;
    digits *= 10;
}
digits = digits/10;
n = n_copy;
stringstream line1, line2, line3;
while (n) {
    int d = n / digits;
    n = n % digits;
    digits /= 10; 
    line1 << top_line[d] << "   ";
    line2 << middle_line[d] << "   ";
    line3 << bottom_line[d] << "   ";
}
cout << line1.str() << endl << line2.str() << endl << line3.str() << endl;
```

Demo : [Ideone](https://ideone.com/KVOrqP)

Comment: I was thinking about that, but i believed it was ugly. Anyway thanks!

Comment: You can make constant arrays so you don't have to write lots and lots of if conditions. Let me put that in the answer.

Comment: @PaulR I lost track. Will fix it.